# I am trying to download data from REST API to azure data lake via azure data factory. How can I pass query parameters for API in azure data factory?

Tags: rest, parameters, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, query-string

I am doing this using ‘Copy Activity’. Is there any other activity that can better perform this operation?
Example REST API URL:https://xzy.com/servicename?name=tom&age=50&city=boston&......
I am putting 'https://xzy.com/servicename/' as the base URL for the linked service.
How to pass the query parameters 'name=tom' and 'age=50' and 'city=boston' to the base url in the azure data factory to get the response? 
Will the parameters be passed at linked service, dataset or pipeline level?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?If so,you could accept it to end this case.Thx.

Comment: hi,any progress here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your request method is `Get`. You could only set the query parameters behind base url directly.

For example,i test rest api from this sample [website](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/):

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1
```

Test result:

[image]

If your request method is `Post`,i suppose you have to define the parameters in the `Body` part.

[image]